# PDFBox no class definition found java.awt.color.ColorSpace

Tags: android, pdfbox

when crating object in android studio:

```
PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
```

I got error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.awt.color.ColorSpace

How to fix this?

P.S.
I imported `pdfbox`, `commons-logging` dependecies.

Comment: You need to use PDFBox for Android, not Apache PDFBox.

Comment: Thank, it works :)